# Sending Byte Array as POST along with BasicNameValuePairs

Tags: java, php, http, post, apache-commons

I am trying to send data to a server as POST data. I have 3 fields, one is a String, another is a TIMEDATE and the last is a BLOB.

I have been trying the following code but it doesn't seem to work. I can't turn the byte array into a String and I am unsure how to append the byte array as a parameter.

If anybody has an idea I would appreciate to hear from you !

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/add_new_profile");

   ProfileData profileData = getProfileData();
   try {
      List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",profileData.getName()));
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("created",profileData.getTimeCreated()));

      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("profile_data",new String(profileData.getDataAsByteArray())));


      post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

      HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
      String line = "";
      while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
      }

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Server PHP script:

```
<?php
include('connect_db.php');
include('tools.php');

$name = $_POST['name'];
$created = $_POST['created'];
$profile_data = $_POST['profile_data'];

$query = "INSERT INTO fingerprint_profiles(name,created,fingerprint) VALUES ('".$name."','".$created"','".$fingerprint_data."')";

$result = mysql_query($query);
print_as_json($result);

?>
```

Comment: How does `getDataAsByteArray` transform your object into an array of bytes? Also, you will want to specify the encoding being used to convert your byte array to String.

Comment: getDataAsByteArray returns a separate byteArray field within profileData.

Comment: Well, thats not what I was asking, but in any case, what error or unexpected behavior are you getting?

Comment: Nothing is being added to the server... I don't know how to turn the byte array into a BLOB format that I can send via POST

Comment: In your PHP script, modify your result line to `$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Could not perform select query - " . mysql_error());` That will clue you in to if a SQL error is occurring. On your client side, check the response status code to make sure the request didn't bomb - `if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) // handle error`.

Comment: I put those lines in, the php script doesn't print any errors but the status code is never equal to 200.. any idea where I could go from here ?

Comment: I just noticed your query line is pretty much completely wrong (mixed delimiters, missing delimiters etc). `mysql_` functions are actually deprecated, you might want to consider switching to mysqli.